# How to show that $\mathrm{Sym}_{n\times n}(\Bbb{R})$ and $\mathrm{Skew}_{n\times n}(\Bbb{R})$ are subspaces of $\mathrm{M}_{n\times n}(\Bbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

A matrix $M \in \mathrm{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is called symmetric (respectively, skew-symmetric) if $M^t = M$ (respectively, $M^t = -M$). How does one prove that the sets $\mathrm{Sym}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathrm{Skew}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ of all symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices in $\mathrm{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ respectively are subspaces of $\mathrm{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$?

---

What I've got as a "proof" so far:

Clearly, any $n\times n$ matix with all entries zero is symmetric because if each $a_{ij}=0$, then $a_{ij}=a_{ji}=0$. Furthermore, this is also the case for all skew-symmetic matrices with all entries zero, for if each $a_{ij}=0$, then $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}=0$; thus, $\Theta \in \mathrm{Sym}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\Theta \in \mathrm{Skew}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$. If $M_1, M_2 \in \mathrm{Sym}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$, $a \in F$, then---by the component-wise nature of addition and the definition of scalar multiplication for matrices---we have that

$$\begin{align*}
aM_1 + M_2 & =  aa_{ij}+b_{ij}\\
& = aa_{ji}+b_{ji} \in \mathrm{Sym}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}).
\end{align*}$$

This is similarly the case for skew-symmetric matrices $M_1, M_2 \in \mathrm{Skew}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$, $a \in F$, then

$\begin{array}{rcl}
aM_1 + M_2 & = & aa_{ij}+b_{ij}\\
& = & -aa_{ji}-b_{ji} \in \mathrm{Skew}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}).
\end{array}$

Thus, both sets are subspaces of $\mathrm{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$.

---

Any good? I'm looking for strong criticism...

Comment: @user1205935 What are you saying? Be more clear please.

Comment: This looks good. You could also note that these subsets also both occur as the kernels of some natural linear maps.

Comment: @AlexYoucis What do you mean "subgroup"?

Comment: I misread your post. Look again, it looks fine to me! Goodjob!

Comment: Sorry I hadn't finished reading your proof, which seems complete to me.

Comment: It doesn't seem immediately obvious that $-aa_{ji}-b_{ji}$ is skew-symmetric. Any clarification would be nice.

Comment: These sets are the kernels of the linear maps $M\longmapsto M-M^t$ and $M\longmapsto M+M^t$ respectively. To see why they are linear, all you need to do is check that $M\longmapsto M^t$ is linear.

Comment: I think I meant $(Sym/Skew)_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ not $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$, right?

Comment: What is to be linear again?

Answer (score 1):

*This CW post intends to remove the question from the unanswered queue.*

As already noted in the comments, your proof works fine. (I would rather write something like $(aa_{ij}+b_{ij})_{ij}$, so that there is not the confusion it could be a scalar, although here it is clear from the context).

As others remarked, another to prove that this is a subspace is to note that it is the kernel of the linear map $M\mapsto M\pm M^t$. Since sums of linear maps are linear, this amounts to showing that $M\mapsto M^t$ is a linear map. This would be a very similar computation to the computations you have.